# GPA input confusion

Tags: java, android

Let's write your name and gpa, and if your GPA is 3 or above, it should say that it will accept you for the job, and if it isn't then it won't. So it all seems to be working but it's not registering the number? Like no matter what number I put it says that you are not accepted for the job. I am unclear what code I have to put to make sure it knows the input is a number/it knows if the number is greater than 3. Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //references to two objects: EditText and Button
        final EditText inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameET);
        Button clickB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showBTN);
        final EditText inputGpa = (EditText) findViewById(gpaET);
        final TextView outputa = (TextView) findViewById(messageTV);

        final int gpaET = 0;

        //setting up a listener to the clickB
        clickB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                //reading the user name input
                String userName = inputName.getText().toString();

                double n1 = Double.valueOf(inputGpa.getText().toString());

                if(gpaET >= 3) {
                    outputa.setText("Hello, " + userName + "With your current gpa, you will be considered for the job.");
                }else {
                    outputa.setText("Hello, " + userName + "With your current gpa, you will not be considered for the job, sorry.");
                }
            }});
    }}
```

Comment: your gpaET is set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are not comparing the input but rather your constant, try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //references to two objects: EditText and Button
        final EditText inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameET);
        Button clickB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showBTN);
        final EditText inputGpa = (EditText) findViewById(gpaET);
        final TextView outputa = (TextView) findViewById(messageTV);


        //setting up a listener to the clickB
        clickB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //reading the user name input
                String userName = inputName.getText().toString();

                //This is where you get the numeric input
                double n1 = Double.valueOf(inputGpa.getText().toString());



                if(n1 >= 3) {
                    outputa.setText("Hello, " + userName + "With your current gpa, you will be considered for the job.");
                }

                else {
                    outputa.setText("Hello, " + userName + "With your current gpa, you will not be considered for the job, sorry.");
                }


            }

        });
    }
}
```